# SQLAlchemy: session.query.one() and session.add() in one transaction

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I want to add row with `VALUE1` to table `TABLE1` only if `TABLE2` have row with `VALUE2`

I can do something like that:

```
session.query(TABLE2)
    .filter(TABLE2.FIELD2 == VALUE2)
    .update({TABLE2.FIELD2: VALUE2}) # without change. only for check
session.add(TABLE1(FIELD1=VALUE1))
session.commit()
```

But I think it is strange that I use `update` without any update.

I want to use `one` instead of `update` but it doesn't support transactions.

UPDATED: this solution is wrong...

This simple solution is wrong also:

```
my_flag = session.query(TABLE2).filter(TABLE2.FIELD2 == VALUE2).first()
# database can be updated here!
if my_flag:
    session.add(TABLE1(FIELD1=VALUE1))
    session.commit()
```

Comment: You update to exactly the same value. You basically say: if `key2 == val2`, then `key2 = val2`. So the update is "invisible", since it does not changes anything.

Comment: Yes, I know. I doing it only to get an error in transaction if `TABLE2` doesn't has the value

Comment: Why don't you use a select query to check if table2 has the value?

Comment: But you do not get an error if it does not has that value. If `filter` does not find any value, then simply no row is updated. No exception will be rissen.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem oh... yes. my miss. And what can I do?

Comment: @matino how can I do it in one transaction?

Comment: Do you have unique key on TABLE1.VALUE1? If so, you can simply try inserting and rollback in case there was a concurrent insert of the same value.

Comment: I wont to do something like this: `if Table2[id].state == 'ready for add new data' then Table1.add(new_data) else raise an error`

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a unique key on `TABLE1.VALUE1`, you could first query 
`TABLE2` and try to insert to `TABLE1`. In case the `VALUE1` already exists in `TABLE1`, the error will be thrown and you will be able to rollback the transaction.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import exists

value_exists = session.query(exists().where(TABLE2.KEY2 == VALUE2)).scalar()
if not value_exists:
    return
try:
    dbsession.add(...)
    dbsession.commit()
except IntegrityError as e:
    dbsession.rollback()
    raise e
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't have a unique key in TABLE2 (except `id` but it don't help). So database can be changed between check TABLE2 and add data to TABLE1

Comment: Ok, then I see 2 solutions left: 1) you insert in the same transaction that changes `state` to `ready for add new data` 2) you could add `for update` to the select query, but this will only work, if the VALUE1 is always the same for given VALUE2 i.e. `('foo', 'bar')` and `('xxx', 'bar')` are impossible. Otherwsie you can't enforce data uniqness without the unique key.